# You earned *-*5 reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, top-bar, tooltips

When hovering over a site's logo in the 'Achievements' dropdown box where your net rep change is negative, it says (emphasis mine):

> You *earned* **-5** reputation

Now, I agree that isn't *wrong*, but it doesn't sound right. It kind of feels like the system's *mocking* me (yes - it bothers me *that* much!).

Can it be changed to check whether the net change is -ve and if it is, then say:

> You *lost* **5** reputation

[image]

Comment: Stack Exchange is becoming self-aware and sarcastic it seems...

Comment: At least they could use a proper minus sign, i.e., −5 instead of -5.

Comment: I lost more than you ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hmmm.. didn't see that! Thanks :) Good - I wouldn't want to lose 30!! :P

Comment: Sure thing, that's what you have Meta lurkers like me for! :-D